# Is ring automorphism of the field of formal Laurent series over a finite field continuous?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ring $F=\mathbb{F}_q((T))$ of formal Laurent series over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. $F$ is a field and there is a valuation $v$ of $F$:
$$v\left(\sum_{i=n}a_iT^i\right)=n$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z},a_i\in\mathbb{F}_q,a_n\neq0$.

$\phi$ is a ring automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_q((T))$. Is $\phi$ continuous? Or there exists a ring automorphism $\phi$ which is not a continuous mapping?

Comment: I don't think this mapping is what you want.

Comment: I was told that $\phi$ must be continuous. But I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=q-1$. Observe that a nonzero element of $\mathbf F_q((T))$ has an $r^n$-th root, for all natural integers $n$, if and only if it belongs to the subset $1+T\mathbf F_q[[T]]$ of $\mathbf F_q((T))$. It follows that any unitary ring endomorphism $\phi$ of the ring $\mathbf F_q((T))$ maps the subset $T\mathbf F_q[[T]]$ into itself. This implies continuity of $\phi$.